# How Do I Make An Ansible Playbook Skip A Role?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to skip the upgrade part of my playbook. The key part looks like this:

```
hosts: linux_group
name: Upgrade the third-party application
roles:
  - role: "upgradeEnv"
    when: ENV == inventory_hostname
vars:
  logdir: "/home/appuser/external/logs"
become_user: "{{ sudoUser }}"
become_method: sudo
become: yes
tags:
  - upgrade
```

And the key part of the role looks like this:

```
- name: Upgrade database
  shell: "upgradeDB.sh {{ env }}"
  vars:
    DBURL: "{{ user }}@{{ host }}"
  no_log: True
  register: register_appupgrade
  tags:
    - upgrade

- fail:
    msg: "Upgrade errors:"
  when: register_appupgrade.stderr !=""
  tags:
    - upgrade
```

I run the playbook with `--skip-tags=upgrade` but ansible still goes into the role and runs the tasks so I end up with `tags: upgrade` specified on each task.

The `Upgrade database` gets skipped but the `fail` ends the run due to the `when` condition.

Why is the role being run from the playbook even when the tags are supposed to be skipped?

Why is the `fail` task not being skipped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the project for testing

```
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── roles
    └── upgradeEnv
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml

3 directories, 4 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[linux_group]
test_11
test_13
```

---

*ansible [core 2.14.1]*

The [tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tags) keyword means the tags are applied to all tasks at the indentation level.

1. If you apply *tags* at the play level

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: linux_group
  roles:
    - role: upgradeEnv
      when: ENV == inventory_hostname
  tags: upgrade
```

everything will be skipped

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --skip-tags=upgrade

PLAY [linux_group] ***************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
```

2. If you apply *tags* at the role level

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: linux_group
  roles:
    - role: upgradeEnv
      when: ENV == inventory_hostname
      tags: upgrade
```

the role will be skipped

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --skip-tags=upgrade

PLAY [linux_group] ***************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************
ok: [test_13]
ok: [test_11]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=
```

3. You'll see the same result if you omit *tags* at role level and apply *tags* at each task in the role

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: linux_group
  roles:
    - role: upgradeEnv
      when: ENV == inventory_hostname
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/upgradeEnv/tasks/main.yml
- name: Upgrade database
  command: "echo {{ env }}"
  register: register_appupgrade
  tags: upgrade

- debug:
    msg: |
      register_appupgrade.stdout: {{ register_appupgrade.stdout }}
      register_appupgrade.stderr: {{ register_appupgrade.stderr }}
  tags: upgrade

- fail:
    msg: Upgrade errors
  when: register_appupgrade.stderr != ""
  tags: upgrade
```

4. If you don't skip tags the play works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e ENV=test_11 -e env=test

PLAY [linux_group] ***************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************
ok: [test_11]
ok: [test_13]

TASK [upgradeEnv : Upgrade database] *********************************************************
skipping: [test_13]
changed: [test_11]

TASK [upgradeEnv : debug] ********************************************************************
skipping: [test_13]
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    register_appupgrade.stdout: test
    register_appupgrade.stderr:

TASK [upgradeEnv : fail] *********************************************************************
skipping: [test_11]
skipping: [test_13]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```